# Limit Evaluation using Taylor Polynomials.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

Consider the following limit problem:$$\lim \limits _{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}.$$It's known that$$e^x=\lim \limits _{n\to \infty}\sum \limits _{r=0}^n\frac{x^r}{r!}\qquad \forall x\in N_0,$$where $N_0$ is a deleted neighbourhood of $0$.

So the original limit gets converted into the following:$$\lim \limits _{x\to 0}\frac{\lim \limits _{n\to \infty}\sum \limits _{r=0}^n\frac{x^r}{r!}-1}{x},$$which simplifies to:\begin{align*}\lim \limits _{x\to 0}\frac{\lim \limits _{n\to \infty}\left (1+\sum \limits _{r=1}^n\frac{x^r}{r!}\right )-1}{x} & =\lim \limits _{x\to 0}\frac{\lim \limits _{n\to \infty}\sum \limits _{r=1}^n\frac{x^r}{r!}}{x} \\
& =\lim \limits _{x\to 0}\left (\lim \limits _{n\to \infty}1+\sum \limits _{r=2}^n\frac{x^{r-1}}{r!}\right ) \\
& =1.
\end{align*}My only problem with the above method is how can we say that the last limit will for sure be $1$? Precisely, how are we so sure that the last summation($\displaystyle \sum \limits _{r=2}^n\frac{x^{r-1}}{r!}$) will be $0$ when both limits (of $n$ and of $x$) are applied to it?

I'm still in high school so I don't know how to evaluate limits using epsilon-delta definition. Is there any other way(other than using  epsilon-delta definition) to convince myself that the last summation indeed is $0$ in the limit?

PS: I know other more efficient ways to approach the above limit problem, however I have a similar type of problem in every limit I evaluate using taylor expansions. So I'm using this limit as a placeholder for my general problem.

Comment: It is difficult to follow your work with your sum indices mismatched vs. the variables used ($i$ vs. $r$).  Also, why have you changed the starting index value so much?  You should see the final index start at $r=1$.

Comment: thank you for the edits and suggestions, I have fixed the problems listed out. I'm still learning to use mathjax and latex so Im sorry for my careless mistakes.

Comment: So basically you want to show that $\displaystyle\sum_{r=2}^n \frac{x^{r-1}}{r!}$ converges.

Comment: Yeah that's basically it but I don't think I can show that without epsilon delta or without using more calculus that I already know, and yet this method is used a lot while solving limits in high school.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...  Epsilon-delta proofs and L'Hopital's rule are much more primitive techniques than using power series.  I think you should learn these concepts first.

Answer (score 2):

In high school? Don't worry about it. Otherwise, there are two fairly straightforward approaches.

Observation number 1: The uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous, and these types of analytic power series converge uniformly (in their radius of convergence). With this observation: $$\sum_{r=2}^\infty\frac{x^{r-1}}{r!}$$Is a continuous function. The limit as $x\to0$ is its evaluation at $0$, so just $0$ as you expect.

Approach 2: We can attempt to explicitly bound. When $|x|\lt1$, $|x|^{r-1}\le|x|$ for all $r\ge2$.

> $$\left|\sum_{r=2}^\infty\frac{x^{r-1}}{r!}\right|\le\sum_{r=2}^\infty\frac{|x|^{r-1}}{r!}\le|x|\cdot\sum_{r=2}^\infty\frac{1}{r!}=|x|\cdot(e-2)$$

Letting $|x|\to0$ gives a clear limit of zero, using this bound.

Comment: so basically, I dont need to worry about it, thank you!

Comment: @RajShukla It depends. In high school problems (I'm not sure what "high school" means for you - in my country, your question is certainly not a high school question) I doubt you'd be facing questions where it is a meaningful issue. However, if you are interested in studying higher maths, you certainly should worry about it... but hopefully you can understand the process of approach 2